# Integer to String, which method is faster?

Tags: java

Which one of the following ways is faster? and what is the difference(s)?

```
int i=0x10;
String s=i+"";
String s1=Integer.toString(i);
String s2=String.valueOf(i);
```

I don't know if there is another way or not.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried doing a benchmark yourself?

Comment: They are the same, just pick one and don't over think about that too much..

Comment: That sounds like "waste of time" for "micro performance optimization"...

Comment: I always use the .toString() since it's easier to see what happens.

Comment: Just write a small program that calculates the time and convert integers to string 1.000.000 times with two ways. Then you can see which one is faster.

Comment: @Andynedine The link you provided is abosuletely untrustworthy, its testing methodology is way off. You can't just write three lines of Java code and call it a microbenchmark.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I just tested myself myself, and I didn't got any differences, while for several tests. each one answered different result. so how can I benchmark it?

Comment: How fast do you need it to be?  What if it too a micro-seocnd longer  but easier to read and understand?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Sir I always use the first one, but I just was wondering which one is faster? maybe in some extreme applications.

Comment: @Joost I tested myself, each run, different results. confused, maybe my CPU is trolling me :(

Comment: @parsaporahmad In extreme applications e.g. high frequency trading, I don't use a Strings for integers at all, that will be the fastest option. ;)

Comment: @parsaporahmad you are not running the test for long enough, you should ignore the first ten thousand tries and average the nest ten thousand or so.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks dude, many thanks, I have to give a try.

Comment: @parsaporahmad In Java 7, `System.out.println(i);` doesn't create a String, it converts straight from an integer to writing to the stream without creating a String. i.e. most likely you can eliminate the need for a String at all if it is just a toString() of the integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Which one of the following ways is faster? and what is the difference(s)?

Take a look at the implementation of `String.valueOf(int)` (in hyperlinked Grepcode format):

```
2942  public static String valueOf(int i) {
2943      return Integer.toString(i, 10);
2944  }
```

This should give you a hint—especially if you are familiar with the concept of *method call inlining* performed routinely by the JIT compiler on `static` method calls.

On the topic of proper microbenchmarking, you should use `jmh` to execute this:

```
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OperationsPerInvocation(1)
@Warmup(iterations = 5, time = 200, timeUnit=MILLISECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 30, time = 200, timeUnit=MILLISECONDS)
@State(Scope.Thread)
@Threads(1)
@Fork(1)
public class Measure
{
  private int arg;

  @Setup public void setup() {
    arg = (int) System.nanoTime();
  }

  @GenerateMicroBenchmark public String integerToString() {
    return Integer.toString(arg);
  }

  @GenerateMicroBenchmark public String stringValueOf() {
    return String.valueOf(arg);
  }

  @GenerateMicroBenchmark public String plus() {
    return ""+arg;
  }
}
```

These were my results:

```
Benchmark                       Mode   Samples         Mean   Mean error    Units
o.s.Measure.integerToString     avgt        30       53.023        8.868    ns/op
o.s.Measure.plus                avgt        30       54.043        6.833    ns/op
o.s.Measure.stringValueOf       avgt        30       52.071        8.217    ns/op
```

Comment: Good point dear, so what about `i+""` and `Integer.toString(i)`

Comment: MANY MANY Thanks dear :D, micro benchmark master.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s1=Integer.toString(i);
String s2=String.valueOf(i);
```

In the above two Integer.toString() will be fast as String.valueOf(i) will call the Integer.toString() method to convert.Below is the implementation of toString method

```
public static String valueOf(int i) {
    return Integer.toString(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s=i+"";
```

In this case first i will be converted into string then it will be appended to string, So already one  conversion of i to string ,Then again concatenation, So it will be slowest compared to the other two options.

```
String s2=String.valueOf(i);
```

This calls `Integer.toString(i, 10);` so it will be slower than direct call to          `Integer.toString(i);`

Finally, comparatively faster will be `Integer.toString(i);`